# How to enable/disable HUD, based on which camera is rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my scene I have a MainCamera and a MiniMapCamera. I also have a HUD that is currently being drawn by both cameras. I would like to remove it from the MiniMapCamera but when I use `Camera.current.name` to check which camera is rendering, It does not work. I am doing this in an `Update()` function. Should I be trying somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jerdak's answer. You can select which layers each camera is supposed to render.

[image]

If you select it in the hierarchy, you can see **Culling Mask** combo box in the `Camera`'s inspector. Throught that you can check the layer a camera is supposed to render. So you can assign a `layer` to your gui elements and let `MiniMapCamera` simply don't render it.

Comment: I must be doing something terribly wrong because I had already tried this method and it did not work. I have no idea where to look.

Comment: If every object has the right tag, it must be culled off if the culling mask relative value is unset.

Comment: For me what worked was to turnoff the GUILayer of the minimap Camera. I dont know of the aftereffects of this action.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you have a mechanism to switch cameras?  If that's the case, use that mechanism to keep track of which camera is currently active.

I don't know if this is still true but `Camera.current` used to have problems when you ran your application in **Unity's editor**.  If that is still the case you might try building your app and seeing what value `Camera.current.name` returns.

**[Update]**

Or you could store your cameras as gameobjects and compare the active camera to the stored cameras to determine which is active.  This solution should only be used intermittently as doing a `FindObjectsOfType` every frame is rarely a good idea.

```
public class CurrentCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera minimapCamera;  
    public Camera mainCamera;

    void FindActiveCamera(){
        Camera[] cameras = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera)) as Camera[];
        foreach (Camera cam in cameras) {
            if(Camera.main == mainCamera)Debug.Log("Found main camera");
            if(Camera.main == minimapCamera)Debug.Log("Found minimap Camera");
        }
    }
    void Update(){
        FindActiveCamera();
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
            minimapCamera.enabled = false;
            mainCamera.enabled = true;
        }
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")){
            minimapCamera.enabled = true;
            mainCamera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**[Update2]**

In order for Camera.main to properly register your camera, the camera object's `Tag` must be set to `MainCamera`. multiple `MainCameras` can be set, just make sure to disable the `Camera` component on the inactive camera or the rendered won't know which to use.

Comment: Unfortunately it never executes the second if statement (minimap). I have also tried `Camera.allCameras` instead of the Find and that did not work either.

Comment: @gaitat Added a full example above (tested and working).  Just make sure both cameras have `Tag` set to `MainCamera` in the editor.

Comment: For me what worked was to turnoff the GUILayer of the minimap Camera. I dont know of the aftereffects of this action.